# How to get Rubysspi 1.3.1 to work with Ruby 1.9.3 and Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, proxy, ntlm

I've recently moved from ruby 1.8.7 to ruby 1.9.3 and am having trouble getting out of my proxy.  Installing gems from the command line works fine but after running the 'apply_sspi_patch' the [readme](https://github.com/m4dc4p/rubysspi/blob/master/README.txt) mentions, which should patch the http.rb file, and running the 'test_patched_net_http.rb' test file I see:

```
  1) Error:
test_net_http(PatchedRubyTest):
ArgumentError: Error occurred during proxy negotiation. req: nil; res: #<Net::HTTPProxyAuthenticationRequired 407 Proxy Authentication Required readbody=true>; Original message: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubysspi-1.3.1/lib/win32/sspi/http_proxy_patch.rb:76:in `request'
    test_patched_net_http.rb:33:in `block in test_net_http'
    test_patched_net_http.rb:32:in `test_net_http'
```

This Corresponds to a line `req["Proxy-Authorization"] = "#{tok} #{n.get_initial_token(tok)}"` n is `n = Win32::SSPI::NegotiateAuth.new`. The NegotiateAuth class does take 1 argument.

Once I updated the http_proxy_patch.rb file require from `require 'win32/sspi'` to `require 'C:\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rubysspi-1.3.1\lib\win32\sspi.rb'` the 'test_patched_net_http.rb' test file passes.

Now when I run tests I'll occasionally get an error similar to:

```
RuntimeError: Error occurred during proxy negotiation. req: "NTLM BUNCH_OF_NUMBERS_AND_LETTERS=="; res: #<Net::HTTPProxyAuthenticationRequired 407 Proxy Authentication Required readbody=true>; Original message: Error: SEC_E_INTERNAL_ERROR
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubysspi-1.3.1/lib/win32/sspi.rb:304:in `complete_authentication'
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubysspi-1.3.1/lib/win32/sspi/http_proxy_patch.rb:91:in `request'
    C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubysspi-1.3.1/lib/win32/sspi/http_proxy_patch.rb:57:in `block in request'
```

- Ruby - ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]
- Rubysspi - 1.3.1
- Selenium-Webdriver - 2.42.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mitigated/removed my issue by modifying the gems\rubysspi-1.3.1\lib\win32\sspi\http_proxy_patch.rb file:

I've added a retry(jretry) in the request method, now I no longer see the error.

```
def request(req, body = nil, &block) # :yield: +response+
  unless started?
    start {
      req['connection'] ||= 'close'
      return request(req, body, &block)
    }
  end
  if proxy_user()
    unless use_ssl?
      req.proxy_basic_auth proxy_user(), proxy_pass()
    end
  end

  req.set_body_internal body
  begin_transport req
    req.exec @socket, @curr_http_version, edit_path(req.path)
    begin
      res = HTTPResponse.read_new(@socket)
    end while res.kind_of?(HTTPContinue)
    if tok = sspi_auth_required?(res)
      jretry = 2
      begin
        n = Win32::SSPI::NegotiateAuth.new
        res.reading_body(@socket, req.response_body_permitted?) { }
        end_transport req, res
        begin_transport req
        if proxy?
          req["Proxy-Authorization"] = "#{tok} #{n.get_initial_token(tok)}"
          req["Proxy-Connection"] = "Keep-Alive"
        else
          req["Authorization"] = "#{tok} #{n.get_initial_token(tok)}"
        end
        # Some versions of ISA will close the connection if this isn't present.
        req["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive"
        req.exec @socket, @curr_http_version, edit_path(req.path)
        begin
          res = HTTPResponse.read_new(@socket)
        end while res.kind_of?(HTTPContinue)
        if (proxy? && res["Proxy-Authenticate"]) || (! proxy? && res["WWW-Authenticate"])
          res.reading_body(@socket, req.response_body_permitted?) { }
          if proxy?
            req["Proxy-Authorization"] = "#{tok} #{n.complete_authentication res["Proxy-Authenticate"]}"
            req["Proxy-Connection"] = "Keep-Alive"
          else
            token = res["WWW-Authenticate"].split(" ").last
            req["Authorization"] = "#{tok} #{n.complete_authentication token}"
          end
          req["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive"
          req.exec @socket, @curr_http_version, edit_path(req.path)
          begin
            res = HTTPResponse.read_new(@socket)
          end while res.kind_of?(HTTPContinue)
        end
      rescue
        if jretry != 0
          jretry -= 1
          retry
        else
          exc = $!.exception("Error occurred during proxy negotiation. req: #{req["Proxy-Authorization"].inspect}; res: #{res.inspect}; Original message: #{$!.message}")
          exc.set_backtrace $!.backtrace
          raise exc
        end
      end
    end

    res.reading_body(@socket, req.response_body_permitted?) {
      yield res if block_given?
    }
  end_transport req, res

  res
end
```